# Discontinuity of function that assigns the matrix pseudoinverse to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be the function that takes a real $m \times n$ matrix and assigns to it its unique $n \times m$ pseudoinverse. Prove that this function is discontinuous.

I presume I need to use matrix norm inequalities in some way but I have no idea how. I'm not even sure which definition of continuity would be the handiest to prove this.

Comment: Just consider the continuity of the pseudoinverse of $\begin{bmatrix} a&0&\cdots \\ 0&0&\cdots \\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots \end{bmatrix}$ as $a\to0$.

Comment: @Rahul Could you expand on this? I don't quite understand.